# Open app as gui via powershell for a specific user

Tags: automation, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2008-r2, app-startup, startupscript

I have an app that needs to run as a GUI, I'm trying to automate it's launch at startup without the need to remote desktop to the windows server 2008 R2 and manually start it. I currently use a powershell script at startup to perform multiple tasks but have not found a way to launch this gui app in the foreground for the user. So for now I still need to remote in and manually kill / start it.

Answer (score 0):

[psexec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) will help you here.

this guy can execute interactively in a remote execution. PowerShell in remoting cannot be used for interactive tasks.